# Understanding What Routers Do

Tags: router

I winter in a trailer park in Florida. They have had free Wi-Fi for years, but you had to be in or near the office to receive it. This summer they are installing antennas around the park, but I have been told that the reception is still very bad. My question is, would a wireless router help improve the reception to my trailer? I plan to get a Smart TV and will also be using it with my Laptop.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Rather than dealing with the crappy free wifi, have you ever considered getting your own dedicated connection? If you could find someone that doesn't do a contract, you could pay a month-to-month fee and have your own reliable connection. Then cancel it whenever you're ready to move back north. Silly snow birds :)

Comment: This is really hard to answer without knowing technical details of how they're extending their wireless coverage, and what your other broadband Internet options might be (LTE? DSL? DOCSIS? Ethernet cable run from the office to your unit?)

Answer (score 3):

Without getting to complex, no a wireless router would not help you.  If the park is installing antennas, more than likely they are working to improve the range of their wireless access points.  I wouldnt purchase anything till you are there and try what they have done.

If you are still receiving a poor signal on your laptop, I would recommend purchasing a better WiFi adapter.  Something like [this](https://www.cdw.com/shop/products/Hawking-Hi-Gain-Wireless-150N-Range-Amplifier-Network-Adapter/2335610.aspx?cm_cat=GoogleBase&cm_ite=2335610&cm_pla=NA-NA-HAW_WI&cm_ven=acquirgy&ef_id=V2gunQAAAKHLft9w:20160721200142:s&gclid=CjwKEAjw5cG8BRDQj_CNh9nwxTUSJAAHdX3fbI8_sla1FZvG5kKIkZ1mX0HdsVtlLvK10qWCllSq2BoCybrw_wcB&s_kwcid=AL!4223!3!61836303859!!!g!18283950120!), with an external antenna will greatly improve your reception.

As for a smart TV...  Personally, I would steer clear of those.  They might seem like a great idea, but generally their interfaces are slow and poorly designed.  Most people, including me, regret buying one.  In addition to that, after a few years, manufacturers stop supporting apps on the TV.  I bought a Samsung smart TV, thinking I would use it for Netflix.  However, the Netflix app interface was just bad.  I also used it occasionally for Skype.  However, Skype support was just recently dropped on that model.  There is no gaurantee the apps will work, or will work well, or will continue to work.  I ended up just plugging a laptop into the TV and that was far better than any app the TV had. Looking back, I should have spent the money on a slightly bigger TV, than a smaller TV with useless apps.